# Making a variable of a variable in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to put the ID from code 1 in to code 2. Can anyone help me? The ID is the logged in user ID. I want to re-use this ID in code 2. As you can see code 2 got ID 1 at the moment, but I need to assign the ID given from code 1 in to code 2 in stead of the ID "1"

Code1:

```
<?php $user_info = get_userdata(1); echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n"; ?>
```

Code2:

```
<?php
$user_id = 1;
$user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id );
echo 'User '.$user_id.'\'s blogs:<ul>';
foreach ($user_blogs AS $user_blog) {
    echo '<li>'.$user_blog->blogname.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

The code will be placed in the same file. I'm trying to merge these 2 insted of using ID 1 in code 2

Comment: What are you trying to do here. The $user_id already has value inside it so why are you setting it again. Your point is not clear

Comment: code 1 has no output, it just generates a string from the blog_id and assignes it to $user_id. what do you want todo ?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of explaining here, Code 1 gives an output of the ID of the logged in user. I want to assign that ID to $user_id in code 2

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Code one gives the blog id of the current blog not of the logged in user. If you want to get the id of the logged in user then you can $user_id = get_current_user_id();

Comment: Context. Codes don't just exist detached. They must reside somewhere. If one of the two is in a function, then the used variables will live in a different scope. And if Code 1 and Code 2 live in different scripts and at different execution times, then this can't work either.

Comment: Can you not just do (in Code2) `$user_id = $user_info->ID`? Or even better, just use `$user_info->ID` instead of `$user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong here. Your code one gives id of the current blog not the user. You need to change your code;

CODE 1:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); //get the current logged in user id
```

CODE 2:

```
$user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id ); //get the blogs of logged in user
echo 'User '.$user_id.'\'s blogs:<ul>';
   foreach ($user_blogs as $user_blog) {
       echo '<li>'.$user_blog->blogname.'</li>';
   }
echo '</ul>';
```

Hope this is what you want :)

EDIT :

This is your current code:

CODE 1:

```
 <?php 
     $user_info = get_userdata(1); 
     echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n"; 
  ?>
```

CODE 2:

```
   <?php $user_id = 1; 
         $user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id ); 
         echo 'User '.$user_id.'\'s blogs:<ul>'; 
         foreach ($user_blogs AS $user_blog) { echo '<li>'.$user_blog->blogname.'</li>'; } echo '</ul>'; 
    ?>
```

Here you are assigning $user_id =1 directly. No need of that. You can do that directly in code 1.

**Just change your current code to this:**

CODE 1:

```
 <?php 
     $user_id = get_current_user_id(); //get the current logged in user id
     echo 'User ID: ' . $user_id . "\n"; 
 ?>
```

CODE 2:

```
   <?php 
         $user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id ); 
         echo 'User '.$user_id.'\'s blogs:<ul>'; 
         foreach ($user_blogs AS $user_blog) { echo '<li>'.$user_blog->blogname.'</li>'; } echo '</ul>'; 
    ?>
```

This will work provided your both codes are in same file.

This is what you want

Comment: That doesnt work. Sorry but I my code was wrong. I have edited my question now. Could you try again?

Comment: ohh, it's almost there. Your code still gives me ID 1, and not the logged in user ID